# Dynamically add ImageView to TableRow

Tags: android

I have a TableLayout in my XML, and I'd like to dynamically add a TableRow with an ImageView to that TableLayout. What I have so far is this:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imgView.setLayoutParams(lp);
imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_test));
tr.addView(imgView);
tlCollection.addView(tr);
```

What am I doing wrong? If I want to add a Textview to the same TableRow, it works, but adding an ImageView doesn't work..

The code for adding a TextView:

```
TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);

myTextView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
myTextView.setText("Test");
tr.addView(myTextView);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, using an LayoutInflater:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

TableRow row = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.collection_row, tlCollection, false);

//fill textview
TextView content = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtCollection);
content.setText("Test");

//fill imageview
ImageView myImgView = ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgCollection);           
myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_icon));

//add row to tablelayout
tlCollection.addView(row);
```

Comment: what does it mean here tlCollection?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the layout params.  You're setting both dimensions to WRAP_CONTENT but the image view doesn't have "content" per se, it has a source drawable.  Try playing around with adjustViewBounds, setScaleType, and the layout params.  Notice that in your example of being able to add a TextView, you're setting the width to FILL_PARENT?

The only example I can find quickly in my open projects of adding an ImageView dynamically in this way was a case in which I was using FILL_PARENT in both directions.  That might not work for you since I'm not doing it exactly the same, but it's worth playing around with these settings as well as the two others mentioned above.

Comment: Doesn't work either. I set them both to FILL_PARENT, but the images are still not shown. Any other idea? The point is, when I add a TableRow with a TextView and ImageView in XML, it does work:

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:layout_span="4" android:stretchColumns="1, 2">
<TableRow>
  <TextView android:text="Test" />
  <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/my_icon" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

Answer (score 0):

try this

ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));

tr.addView(imgView);

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem now its fixed using the below code

```
CandFlag =new ImageView(this);
CandFlag.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

CandFlag.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.flag));


LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) CandFlag.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = 75;
            layoutParams.height = 75;
            CandFlag.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Tablerow.addView(CandFlag);
```