# ImageView In TableLayout

Tags: java, android

I want to add a ImageView in TableLayout. I do all things, but it isn't shown anything. How can I fix it?

This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.buddy_list);

   TableLayout buddy_list_layout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.buddy_list_layout);

    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    TableLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        50);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.troll_logo);
    TableLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    tableRow.addView(imageView, layoutParams2);
    buddy_list_layout.addView(tableRow, layoutParams1);
} // end -> method -> onCreate
```

Comment: Does this need to be dynamic? If not it's easier to do this through xml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a pre-defined xml layout for rows, like someone suggests here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679835/375929 (you probably don't want it completely dynamic, your rows are most likely similar, you just need to add them dynamically) It will save you the effort of `LayoutParams` stuff programmatically.

But yeah, your problem is probably using the wrong LayoutParams class, as matt5784 says.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch layoutParams2 from a `TableLayout.LayoutParams()` to a `TableRow.LayoutParams()`, since you are using it to add a TableRow. The types need to match the layout, otherwise it won't work.